# class file version 54.0,Java Runtime only 52.0, while trying to run docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven, jbi

Im trying to dockerize my application and when I try to run the docker run command, I receive this error. I tried a lot of things where people say that java and javac are different versions, but they are the same; What is the problem in the situation and how can I resolve it? I will apply picture of the error, so you can see it. Also do I need to go back to previous version of java and how to do this? Thanks in advance! :)

[image: Error]

Comment: If `com.redzone.RedZoneApplication` is your class, then `java` (in Docker) and `javac` (on your development machine) can't be the same version; you've compiled with a newer version (which means either upgrade Java used by Docker or downgrade Java used to develop). If it's a library class then you're using a library compiled with a newer version of Java (which means either upgrade Java in Docker or downgrade the dependency).

Answer (score 0):

You have compiled your code with Java 10. Your docker has Java 8 runtime environment.

Comment: Can I run Java 10 environment or somehow I have to compile the code with java 8?

Comment: If you have control over docker image, you can change java environment. If you have control over source code you can compile with java 8.

Comment: How do I make my code to compile with java 8, I already tried to add: 
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target> 
in the properties of the pom file, but it is still not happening.

Comment: You need to install JDK 8 and point your maven to it. If you have multiple JDKs in your environment you can use maven toolchains or a dev env configuration tool like sdkman to change your JDK for a specific project.